# Strange UnsupportedOperationException when calling list.remove(0)

Tags: java, list, collections

I have this method which takes a varargs of Strings, creates a List out of it, and then tries to remove the first element of the list.

```
public void importFrom(String... files) {
    List<String> fileList = Arrays.asList(files);

    String first = fileList.remove(0);
    // other stuff
}
```

But as soon as `remove` gets called, an `UnsupportedOperationException` is thrown. My guess is that the return List-Type does not support the remove method. Am I correct? What alternatives do I have?

Comment: looks like a compilation error. You have 2 variables called files one is a list the other an array. Could you provide compilable code, then we could have a look why you are getting that error.

Comment: The returned list acts as a `view` for the backed array. You can not modify the list.

Comment: @sethu Was just a typo, fixed that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Arrays.asList` only provides a thin wrapper around an array. This wrapper allows you to do *most* operations on an array using the `List` API. A quote from the JavaDoc:

> Returns a **fixed-size** list backed by the specified array.  [...]
>   This method acts as bridge between array-based and collection-based APIs [...]

If you really want to remove something, then this might work:

```
List<String> realList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(stringArray));
```

This one creates a real `ArrayList` (which supports `remove`) and fills it with the contents of another list which happens to be the wrapper around your `String[]`.

Answer (score 4):

`Arrays.asList` provides a List view of the array, BACKED by the array. And arrays are not resizable. Any attempt to change its size will throw an exception.

Answer (score 2):

You could just create a `new ArrayList<String>()`, then loop over all files `for (String file : files) fileList.add(file);`. Or you could use the List you already created and add it to the new ArrayList using `fileList.addAll(files);`

Answer (score 1):

`Arrays.asList()` returns instance of `Arrays.ArrayList` that that is unmodifireable list because it is a simple wrapper over array. You cannot remove elements from array.

This is written in javadoc of `asList()`:

*Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array.*

Comment: It is not unmodifiable.  The javadoc says "(Changes to the returned list "write through" to the array.)".

Answer (score 0):

The returned *list* acts as a `view` for the *backed array*. You can not modify the list directly but only through the backed array. However, you cannot resize the array.